# javascript - how do I access private method of a plugin

Tags: javascript

As shown in below image, I would like to access getTable function. I've tried in this way:

```
var resizeHeaderPlugin = table.getPlugins()[1];
            var objPlugin = Object.getPrototypeOf(resizeHeaderPlugin);
            console.log(objPlugin); // prints as shown in image
            console.log(objPlugin.getTable()); // always prints undefined
```

I am not sure getTable in **super** of constructor and getTable in **proto** are meant to be same or not.

getTable in plugin is defined as:

```
         /**
         * @method getTable
         * @private
         */
        getTable: function () {
            return _(this).table;
        },
```

**How do I access this method and get it's return value ?**

[image]

Comment: please lib name

Comment: @avrilalejandro lib is not in public domain. it's org's internal lib.